# Bash unable to assign value

Tags: bash, variable-assignment, command-substitution

Got a bit of a problem. I'm new to bash and I'm trying my hardest, but I can't figure out how to assign the desired output to the variable. Running this command in the prompt

```
wc -l data.txt | awk '{ print $1 }'
```

yields the result *12*, which is desired. However if I put it in the test.sh file, it won't work. I've tried different quotations, but all I've managed to get is the entire line as a string...

**Test.sh**

```
#! /bin/bash

# Count lines for data.txt files
data1=wc -l data.txt | awk '{ print $1 }'

echo "Lines in data.txt: $data1"

exit
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want:

```
data1="$(wc -l data.txt | awk '{ print $1 }')"
```

The `$()` syntax causes bash to execute that expression and replace it with the results.

Actually, powershell does allow you to do a straight `=` assignment like you did...

Comment: Thanks! This did just what I wanted! I'll look further into $() too see how to use it!

Comment: It's called "command substitution" on the `man bash` page.